# How to return the entire row based on two cells from two different Excel sheets matching?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large Excel data file, with data from two different sheets. I want to be able to match the **partner_identifier** values from **SO Sheet 2** to the values in **BB Sheet 1**. For the rows in **BB Sheet 1** that do match, I want to bring the entire row into a new sheet.

I need help coming up with a formula for this. I've tried `VLOOKUP` and `IF` variations, but I think I need a more complex formula. I can't do an `=IF('SO Sheet 2'!D3='BB Sheet 1'!D3)` because the matching values could be in different rows.

Right now, I have (and I know this is off because it returned "No" for every row, even the ones with a matching value) :

```
=IF(D3='SO Sheet 2'!D3:D16,'BB Sheet 1'!D3,"No")
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version of excel (Excel for Microsoft 365) - you can use XLOOKUP or FILTER formula.

Example:

= FILTER('SO Sheet 2'!A3:D16, 'SO Sheet 2'!D3:D16=D3)

Check here for details about these formulas: [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929), [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)

Comment: This will not work, as it will filter only D3, he needs to extract the full matching rows

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result in 2 steps. in Sheet "BB sheet 1", you need to add a column E with  XLOOKUP formula to find the matching identifier in "SO sheet 2"

```
=XLOOKUP(D2,'SO Sheet 2'!$A$2:$A$14,'SO Sheet 2'!$A$2:$A$14,"No")
```

The above will list all the matching identifier and put "No" wherever if couldn't match the identifier.

Then all you got to do is , in a new sheet, enter the formula in cell A1

```
=FILTER('BB sheet 1'!A:D,'BB sheet 1'!E:E<>"No")
```

Comment: I tried the first part of your answer, the XLOOKUP (I'm not terribly familiar with XLOOKUP's, but this looks extremely helpful!), I keep getting an error message. However, the syntax looks right and I've triple checked it, so I'm not sure what's causing the error.

Comment: upload a link to your file, may be i can check

Comment: Thank you, that would be great. The XLOOKUP formula you suggested is in column G on the BB Sheet 1 page. Here's a link: https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?cid=5d6272448f770028&page=view&resid=5D6272448F770028!109&parId=5D6272448F770028!101&app=Excel

Comment: cannot access the link, says owner did not give permission, better to put up a wetransfer link

Comment: Hmm that's odd. I just checked and the permissions are now anyone with the link can access. Maybe this one will work: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AigAd49EcmJdbUuzIS5bdghWgKc?e=pr9VeX

Comment: i have updated the file, in partner id , i guess the letter "n" was missing which i fixed